# Bulma select dropdown not showing on Safari

Tags: bulma

Bulma select dropdown not showing the dropdown on Safari browser; even it causes Safari to freeze when clicking repeatedly on select dropdown.
I can reproduce the issue on macOS Mojave version 10.14.6 with Safari version 13.0.1.
The issue occurs on any sites with Bulma select, even on the official Bulma site:
https://bulma.io/documentation/form/select/
Is this a Bulma/Safari bug? Any workaround/solution?

Comment: why don't you raise an issue to [bulma github](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma) if you think it's a bug

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be know now.
There are some workarounds on [this thread on ghithub](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/2626).

Answer (score 1):

This issue was not just occurring for Bulma, but for all select tags with styling inside the tags (in my case, it was `appearance: none`, `background-color: <any>`, and `border: 0` on the `select` tag) on any new Safari versions (13+) using MacOS Mojave (see below for more details). I can confirm that adding this snippet globally fixed my issue:

```
select {
  text-rendering: auto !important;
}
```

The bug was only occurring for `Safari v13+` on Mac OS Mojave (`Version 10.14.6`). I checked on `Safari 13.0.1` and `13.0.2`, and both were breaking, but `Safari 12.1.2` was working just fine. With the snippet above, it should work perfectly fine for `v13+`.